# Bootstrap Justified Collapse Button Group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a Bootstrap justified button group, where each button opens a collapsed `<div>` beneath it.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid bg-grey text-center" id="about">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="about1-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#about1">Forms &amp Websites</button>
            </div>
            <div id="about1" class="collapse">
                <p>C# Windows Apps and Microsoft Azure Database Integration</p>
                <p>HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, and MySQL</p>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="about2-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#about2">Computer Architecture</button>
            </div>
            <div id="about2" class="collapse">
                <p>Combinational/Sequential Circuitry, Assembly Language</p>
                <p>Thread-Level Multiprocessing and Process Scheduling</p>
                <p>Networks and OS Integration</p>
            </div>

            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-info" id="about3-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#about3">Programming Concepts (C++)</button>
            </div>
            <div id="about3" class="collapse">
                <p>OOP, Inheritance &amp Polymorphism</p>
                <p>Memory Management, Advanced/Custom Data Structures</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in the first button (left) opening its div weirdly with part of the button disappearing, and the other two buttons not opening their content at all.

I feel I am close but may not have nested the `<div>`s correctly.

Comment: You have missing quotes. For example check `id="about3-btn data-toggle="collapse"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the [events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) to make it only show one at a time
I think this may give you a better result

I moved the elements to their own row to make it more scalable in case you add more buttons and more responsive for device sizes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sub').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#sub .collapse').collapse('hide')
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid bg-grey text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" id="myCollapsible">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="about1-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub" data-target="#about1">Forms &amp Websites</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="about2-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub" data-target="#about2">Computer Architecture</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-info" id="about3-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub" data-target="#about3">Programming Concepts (C++)</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="sub">
    <div id="about1" class="collapse">
      <p>C# Windows Apps and Microsoft Azure Database Integration</p>
      <p>HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, and MySQL</p>
    </div>

    <div id="about2" class="collapse">
      <p>Combinational/Sequential Circuitry, Assembly Language</p>
      <p>Thread-Level Multiprocessing and Process Scheduling</p>
      <p>Networks and OS Integration</p>
    </div>

    <div id="about3" class="collapse">
      <p>OOP, Inheritance &amp Polymorphism</p>
      <p>Memory Management, Advanced/Custom Data Structures</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close, but this caused all of the "about" `<div>`s to stack on top of each other in the same spot when expanded. I wrapped each one in a size 4 BS column and that finished the job. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the nesting is wrong.  Try to put the divs with 'about' ids within the divs with the 'btn-group' classes.

```
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-info" id="about1-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#about1">Forms &amp Websites</button>
        <div id="about1" class="collapse">
            <p>C# Windows Apps and Microsoft Azure Database Integration</p>
            <p>HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, PHP, and MySQL</p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Also, as already mentioned, you are missing quotes.

Comment: Thanks, they now open in the correct direction. However, clicking one causes the other two to readjust to be vertically centered. The one that's clicked stays at the top while the others slide down to the middle.

Comment: @possum_pendulum my answer should resolve that issue let me know if find it useful